# Proving Convergence or Divergence for $\int_0^{\pi} \frac{\ln(x)}{\sqrt{\sin(x)}}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence

I have some integral $$\int_0^{\pi} \frac{\ln(x)}{\sqrt{\sin(x)}}\,dx$$
I have no idea how to prove its convergence or divergence, which method helps me do it?

Comment: $\sin(x)\sim x$ at $x\rightarrow0_+$  and $\sin(x)\sim \pi-x$ at $x\rightarrow \pi_-$  which means that the singularties of the integrand are integrable (after taking into account the square root) and therefore the integral converges

Comment: for x near 0 $$ sin(x) \sim 0 $ so near 0 your integral behaves as $ x^{-1/2-e} $ for some small 'e' number , therefore, your integral is CONVERGENT

Comment: @tired sorry, i don't understand how you become that the singularties of the integrand  caused integral convergence. Can you please expain this?

Comment: for example, locally near $x=0$ the integrand looks like $\log(x)/\sqrt{x}$ wich is integrable

Answer (score 2):

In a right neighbourhood of the origin the integrand function behaves like $\frac{\log x}{\sqrt{x}}$ and 
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log x}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx = -4 $$
is convergent. Similarly, in a left neighbourhood of $\pi$ the integrand function behaves like $\frac{\log\pi}{\sqrt{\pi -x}}$ and
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\pi -x}} = 2\sqrt{\pi} $$
is convergent as well. In any compact sub-interval of $(0,\pi)$ the integrand function is bounded, hence it follows that the given integral is finite. We also have:

$$ I_1 = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\log x}{\sqrt{\sin x}}\,dx = 4\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\pi/2}}\log(x)\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{\sin x^2}}\,dx$$
with $I_1<0$ and $|I_1|<\sqrt{8\pi}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\pi/2}}(-\log x)\,dx<5$ and 
$$ 0<I_2 = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\log\left(\pi-x\right)}{\sqrt{\sin x}}\,dx < \log(\pi)\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\sin x}}=\sqrt{2}\log(\pi)K\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)<\pi $$
hence $I=I_1+I_2$ lies between $-5$ and $\pi$.

Comment: Can you please clarify the following: we have an integral $\int \limits_0^{\pi} \frac{\log x}{\sqrt{\pi - x}}dx$ and then, as I understood, you say that from convergence of $\int \limits_0^{\pi} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\pi - x}}$ it follows that $\int \limits_0^{\pi} \frac{\log x}{\sqrt{\pi - x}}dx$ is also convergent. I don't really see why these two integrals are connected.

Comment: @user6323104: I am not saying that. What I am saying is that the convergence of the given integral is granted by the integrability of $\frac{\log x}{\sqrt{x}}$ in a right neighbourhood of zero and by the integrability of $\frac{\log \pi}{\sqrt{\pi-x}}$ in a left neighbourhood of $\pi$, that is equivalent to the integrability of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ in a right neighbourhood of the origin.

Comment: Oh, now I see it! Thanks!